# NT SQL Connecting

Tags: c#, .net, sql

how can i connect win nt sqlexpress?
i am using this code to connect.it works with any version and kind of sql.

```
internal string GetConnectionString() 
{ 
      return "Data Source=" + "MyPC\SQLExpress" + 
              ";Initial Catalog=Master;User ID=" + username + 
              ";Password=" + password; 
}
```

when connectiong with express ===>>>

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

or

Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

or

Login failed for user 'sysadmin'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Comment: Have a look at the SqlConnectionStringBuilder ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx ). This is a better way of programmatically generating Connection Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following to the connection string:

```
Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

If you are trying to use windows credentials you will need to set:

```
Integrated Security=true;
```

This will use Windows authentication rather than SQL authentication. If you don't spesify a user name and password, the currently logged in user will be used implicitly.

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005 for more details.